# Java (JSP) not printing out the "0x0a" or "\n" new line in system.out.println

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, ascii

Ok first of all, I'm developing a OCR. Tesseract returns a chunk of string to me in a txt file. I am supposed to read the text file and display it on the jsp.

Currently, my text is like this when viewing on Windows Notepad:

```
Hello World!This is a sample text.
```

Viewing on Notepad++:

```
Hello World!
This is a sample text.
```

When I run my code(shown below) in jsp by reading the file, it displays like what Windows Notepad shows, not like Sublime Text Editor. I wanted the text to line break,not joined together.

```
<%
            String file_name=(String)request.getParameter("file_name");
            String file_name_given=(String)request.getParameter("file_name_given");
            //creating the out put file after upload and reading
            create_file obj_create_file=new create_file();
            obj_create_file.create_output_file(file_name);
            //read the created out put file
            read_file obj_read_file=new read_file();
            String read=obj_read_file.read_file(file_name);
            System.out.println(read);
%>
```

How can I modify the code in a way that it displays the breakline, instead of a continuous string? I'm suspecting it has to do with ASCII character "0x0a".

Answer (score 2):

The stuff you send to the browser from a JSP is *typically* interpreted as HTML.  In HTML, linefeed characters are just whitespace.  They don't give you a line break.

To get a line break in HTML, you need to output a `<br>` or a `<p>` or something like that.  If this doesn't "ring any bells" for you, I suggest that you find and read an HTML tutorial or textbook

Comment: You are right. Currently, when I try to System.out.println the text locally, it is also not showing the line break, but showing everything in one line. Maybe I modify my question. Because the problem lies between java reading the file and printing it, not on the html side.

Comment: Your observation about the console output could be to do with platform-specific line separators.  "\n" on Linux versus "\r\n" on Windows.  That's not Java's fault.